# Jquery - Any idea where to find an already made plugin for sliding images?

Tags: jquery

I can't think of what to even search for in google (not sure what you would call this plugin). So I've been using this:

http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

But literally I only use it for the bottom sliding navigation.

The things is, I'm not using a lot of the functionality, so in reality it's pretty bloated.

What would you call that part of a plugin, or better yet, where would I find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below links -

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCarouselLite

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption

That one has basic functionality. Just the sliding image with an optional transparent section for caption text.

Comment: That's sort of the opposite of what I need. I don't need a slideshow, I only need the navigation aspect of the plugin I mentioned. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this one:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/